# How can I rotate the canvas image?

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I tried to load the image by url on the canvas. And I change the canvas size to image size. andf I tried to rotate the image but if I executed it, some part of the image is cropped. Please find the errors in my code.

```
if (submitBtn) {
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', handleSubmitBtnClick);
}

function handleSubmitBtnClick() {
  let imgURLValue = inputImageURL.value;
  backgroundImage.src = `${imgURLValue}`;
  backgroundImage.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  backgroundImage.onload = function () {
    canvas.width = backgroundImage.width;
    canvas.height = backgroundImage.height;
    ctx.drawImage(
      backgroundImage,
      0,
      0,
      backgroundImage.width,
      backgroundImage.height
    );
  };
}
```

```
if (rotateBtn) {
  rotateBtn.addEventListener('click', handleRotateBtn);
}

function handleRotateBtn() {
  degree += 90;
  if (degree >= 360) {
    degree = 0;
  }

  if (degree === 0 || degree === 180) {
    canvas.width = backgroundImage.width;
    canvas.height = backgroundImage.height;
  } else {
    canvas.width = backgroundImage.height;
    canvas.height = backgroundImage.width;
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(backgroundImage.width / 2, backgroundImage.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate((degree * Math.PI) / 180);

  ctx.drawImage(
    backgroundImage,
    0,
    0,
    backgroundImage.width,
    backgroundImage.height,
    -backgroundImage.width / 2,
    -backgroundImage.height / 2,
    backgroundImage.width,
    backgroundImage.height
  );

  ctx.restore();
}
```

[enter image description here][1]

If I rotate the image, the image is loaded like this..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drNaG.png

Comment: I think you can try to put the canvas in the container and move the container then.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of your rotation should be the center of the canvas, so that it uses the updated width and height values.
By using the original center of the image your drawing will be offset.

```js
const rotateBtn = document.querySelector("button");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = "https://picsum.photos/150/300";
backgroundImage.decode().then(() => {
  rotateBtn.disabled = false;
  handleRotateBtn();
});
let degree = -90;


if (rotateBtn) {
  rotateBtn.addEventListener('click', handleRotateBtn);
}

function handleRotateBtn() {
  degree += 90;
  if (degree >= 360) {
    degree = 0;
  }

  if (degree === 0 || degree === 180) {
    canvas.width  = backgroundImage.width;
    canvas.height = backgroundImage.height;
  } else {
    canvas.width  = backgroundImage.height;
    canvas.height = backgroundImage.width;
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();

  // use the updated center as origin
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate((degree * Math.PI) / 180);
  
  // I simplified this call but it does the same as yours
  ctx.drawImage(
    backgroundImage,
    -backgroundImage.width / 2,
    -backgroundImage.height / 2
  );
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas { background: ivory }
```

```html
<button disabled>rotate</button><br>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! You're genius!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers